# Почему пустой блок <w:r> внутри которого пустой блок <w:t> отображается как пробел?

Tags: xml, ms-word, office, openxml

[Образец документа](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t-3c3p5bu2eonU-VoWOaPjQsZKnqcJCN/view?usp=sharing) Исследуя один документ .docx, обнаружил пробелы, которые в самом документе не отображаются.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Начал копаться глубже. Обнаружил, что пробелами являются блоки <w:r> внутри которых пустые <w:t>.

```
<w:r w:rsidRPr="002811C7">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
                <w:noProof/>
                <w:sz w:val="28"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="28"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>ако вышепе</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r w:rsidR="002811C7" w:rsidRPr="002811C7">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
                <w:noProof/>
                <w:sz w:val="28"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="28"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>р</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r w:rsidR="002811C7" w:rsidRPr="002811C7">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="MS Gothic" w:eastAsia="MS Gothic" w:hAnsi="MS Gothic" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
                <w:noProof/>
                <w:spacing w:val="-20"/>
                <w:sz w:val="28"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="28"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t></w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="002811C7">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
                <w:noProof/>
                <w:sz w:val="28"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="28"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>ечисле</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r w:rsidR="002811C7" w:rsidRPr="002811C7">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
                <w:noProof/>
                <w:sz w:val="28"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="28"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>н</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r w:rsidR="002811C7" w:rsidRPr="002811C7">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="MS Gothic" w:eastAsia="MS Gothic" w:hAnsi="MS Gothic" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
                <w:noProof/>
                <w:spacing w:val="-20"/>
                <w:sz w:val="28"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="28"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t></w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r w:rsidR="002811C7" w:rsidRPr="002811C7">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
                <w:noProof/>
                <w:sz w:val="28"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="28"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>н</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r w:rsidR="002811C7" w:rsidRPr="002811C7">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="MS Gothic" w:eastAsia="MS Gothic" w:hAnsi="MS Gothic" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
                <w:noProof/>
                <w:spacing w:val="-20"/>
                <w:sz w:val="28"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="28"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t></w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="002811C7">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
                <w:noProof/>
                <w:sz w:val="28"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="28"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>ые п</w:t>
        </w:r>
```

Не могу понять, как выключить эту настройку.

Comment: Я в слове "вышеперечисленные" вижу пустой блок w:t, но пробела не вижу.

Comment: В самом документе пробел не отображается. Если вы посмотрите на результат поиска на картинке, там проблемы есть.

Comment: Я не считаю что это настройка, я думаю это баг ворда связанный с редактированиями, ворд и правда беспорядочно создаёт "теги" для форматирования, и может бросать теги "пустыми". Ну это чисто мнение.

Comment: Практический вопрос. 1. Где образец? Дайте ссылку на этот образец, и желательно что бы там была 1 страница, а не 100 и больше. Или какие действия нужно выполнить что бы мы у себя могли повторить ваш баг?

Comment: 2. Желательно название программы и версия. Т.к. в разных версиях могут быть разные баги. Может в новой версии ворда это исправили. (Может это и не ворд)

Comment: Ну и добалю, что для исправления этой проблемы, нужно или модифицировать документ, или найти версию программы где нету бага. Возможно нажимая на какие-то пункты меню можно очистить документ от лишних преобразований. Возможно это можно исправить макросами, а возможно средствами ворд это исправить нельзя.

Comment: 1. Это не баг ТОЧНО. Это искусственно созданное явление, пытаясь пройти системы проверки оригинальности текста такие как антиплагиат.
2. Программа Word 2016. Но само это явление действительно для формата .docx. Неважно какая программа используется.
3. Задача модифицировать имеющийся документ. Образец файла прикрепил.